# tomcat-maven-plugin using Tomcat 7 - tomcat:deploy works, tomcat:undeploy doesn't

Tags: tomcat, maven, plugins, pom.xml

I have a working configuration for tomcat:deploy, but when I come to undeploy the WAR, I get the following error which has left me foxed:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com:DocBookScratchProject:war:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 166, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DocBookScratchProject 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:undeploy (default-cli) @ DocBookScratchProject ---
[INFO] Undeploying application at http://localhost:8080/DocBookScratchProject
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.769s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 27 10:17:24 BST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/110M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:undeploy (default-cli) on project DocBookScratchProject: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: <html>
[ERROR] <head>
[ERROR] <style>
[ERROR] H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}
[ERROR] table {
[ERROR] width: 100%;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.page-title {
[ERROR] text-align: center;
[ERROR] vertical-align: top;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] font-weight: bold;
[ERROR] background: white;
[ERROR] color: black;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.title {
[ERROR] text-align: left;
[ERROR] vertical-align: top;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] font-style:italic;
[ERROR] font-weight: bold;
[ERROR] background: #D2A41C;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.header-left {
[ERROR] text-align: left;
[ERROR] vertical-align: top;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] font-weight: bold;
[ERROR] background: #FFDC75;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.header-center {
[ERROR] text-align: center;
[ERROR] vertical-align: top;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] font-weight: bold;
[ERROR] background: #FFDC75;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.row-left {
[ERROR] text-align: left;
[ERROR] vertical-align: middle;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] color: black;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.row-center {
[ERROR] text-align: center;
[ERROR] vertical-align: middle;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] color: black;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] td.row-right {
[ERROR] text-align: right;
[ERROR] vertical-align: middle;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] color: black;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] TH {
[ERROR] text-align: center;
[ERROR] vertical-align: top;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] font-weight: bold;
[ERROR] background: #FFDC75;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] TD {
[ERROR] text-align: center;
[ERROR] vertical-align: middle;
[ERROR] font-family:sans-serif,Tahoma,Arial;
[ERROR] color: black;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] form {
[ERROR] margin: 1;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] form.inline {
[ERROR] display: inline;
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] </style>
[ERROR] <title>/manager</title>
[ERROR] </head>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <table cellspacing="4" border="0">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2">
[ERROR] <a href="http://www.apache.org/">
[ERROR] <img border="0" alt="The Apache Software Foundation" align="left"
[ERROR] src="/manager/images/asf-logo.gif">
[ERROR] </a>
[ERROR] <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/">
[ERROR] <img border="0" alt="The Tomcat Servlet/JSP Container"
[ERROR] align="right" src="/manager/images/tomcat.gif">
[ERROR] </a>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <hr size="1" noshade="noshade">
[ERROR] <table cellspacing="4" border="0">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="page-title" bordercolor="#000000" align="left" nowrap>
[ERROR] <font size="+2">Tomcat Web Application Manager</font>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" width="10%"><small><strong>Message:</strong></small>&nbsp;</td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left"><pre>FAIL - Tried to use command /undeploy via a GET request but POST is required</pre></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="4" class="title">Manager</td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left"><a href="/manager/html/list;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">List Applications</a></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><a href="/manager/../docs/html-manager-howto.html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">HTML Manager Help</a></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><a href="/manager/../docs/manager-howto.html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">Manager Help</a></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right"><a href="/manager/status;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">Server Status</a></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="6" class="title">Applications</td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="header-left"><small>Path</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-left"><small>Version</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>Display Name</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>Running</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-left"><small>Sessions</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-left"><small>Commands</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/">/</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>Welcome to Tomcat</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">0</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] &nbsp;<small>Start</small>&nbsp;
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/stop;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Stop"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/reload;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Reload"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/undeploy;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Undeploy"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr><tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Expire sessions">&nbsp;with idle &ge;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idle" size="5" value="30">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/DocBookScratchProject">/DocBookScratchProject</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small>&nbsp;</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/DocBookScratchProject&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">0</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
[ERROR] &nbsp;<small>Start</small>&nbsp;
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/stop;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/DocBookScratchProject&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Stop"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/reload;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/DocBookScratchProject&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Reload"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/undeploy;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/DocBookScratchProject&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Undeploy"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr><tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
[ERROR] <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/DocBookScratchProject&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Expire sessions">&nbsp;with idle &ge;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idle" size="5" value="30">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/help">/help</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>&nbsp;</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/help&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">0</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] &nbsp;<small>Start</small>&nbsp;
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/stop;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/help&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Stop"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/reload;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/help&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Reload"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/undeploy;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/help&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Undeploy"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr><tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/help&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Expire sessions">&nbsp;with idle &ge;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idle" size="5" value="30">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/host%2Dmanager">/host-manager</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small>Tomcat Host Manager Application</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#C3F3C3" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/host%2Dmanager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">0</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
[ERROR] &nbsp;<small>Start</small>&nbsp;
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/stop;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/host%2Dmanager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Stop"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/reload;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/host%2Dmanager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Reload"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/undeploy;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/host%2Dmanager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">  <small><input type="submit" value="Undeploy"></small>  </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr><tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
[ERROR] <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/host%2Dmanager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Expire sessions">&nbsp;with idle &ge;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idle" size="5" value="30">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager">/manager</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>Tomcat Manager Application</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">9</a></small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;Start&nbsp;
[ERROR] &nbsp;Stop&nbsp;
[ERROR] &nbsp;Reload&nbsp;
[ERROR] &nbsp;Undeploy&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr><tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
[ERROR] <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?path=/manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <small>
[ERROR] &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Expire sessions">&nbsp;with idle &ge;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idle" size="5" value="30">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
[ERROR] </small>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2" class="title">Deploy</td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2" class="header-left"><small>Deploy directory or WAR file located on server</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2">
[ERROR] <form method="post" action="/manager/html/deploy;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] <small>Context Path (required):</small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="text" name="deployPath" size="20">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] <small>XML Configuration file URL:</small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="text" name="deployConfig" size="20">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] <small>WAR or Directory URL:</small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="text" name="deployWar" size="40">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] &nbsp;
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="submit" value="Deploy">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2" class="header-left"><small>WAR file to deploy</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2">
[ERROR] <form method="post" action="/manager/html/upload;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98" enctype="multipart/form-data">
[ERROR] <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] <small>Select WAR file to upload</small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="file" name="deployWar" size="40">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-right">
[ERROR] &nbsp;
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="submit" value="Deploy">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2" class="title">Diagnostics</td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2" class="header-left"><small>Check to see if a web application has caused a memory leak on stop, reload or undeploy</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="2">
[ERROR] <form method="post" action="/manager/html/findleaks;jsessionid=724F30BC8ED2E6CE4F8A1EC4CB1E5B50?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=D9447A84FBF3B6DCC2C067BAA2539F98">
[ERROR] <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <input type="submit" value="Find leaks">
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-left">
[ERROR] <small>This diagnostic check will trigger a full garbage collection. Use it with extreme caution on production systems.</small>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] </form>
[ERROR] </td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td colspan="8" class="title">Server Information</td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>Tomcat Version</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>JVM Version</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>JVM Vendor</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>OS Name</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>OS Version</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>OS Architecture</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>Hostname</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="header-center"><small>IP Address</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] <tr>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>Apache Tomcat/7.0.28</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>1.6.0_29-b11</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>Sun Microsystems Inc.</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>Windows 7</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>6.1</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>amd64</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>Mat-PC</small></td>
[ERROR] <td class="row-center"><small>10.201.113.100</small></td>
[ERROR] </tr>
[ERROR] </table>
[ERROR] <br>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <hr size="1" noshade="noshade">
[ERROR] <center><font size="-1" color="#525D76">
[ERROR] <em>Copyright &copy; 1999-2012, Apache Software Foundation</em></font></center>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] </body>
[ERROR] </html>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Tomcat-users.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="standard"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="tomcat,manager,manager-script,manager-gui,standard,admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Maven settings.xml snippet:**

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

**POM snippet:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: hi i have the same problem, and the new tomcat plugin hasn't an undeploy (just update, but i need an real undeploy)... did you solve this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I am still searching. I have resorted to using mvn:package and deploying the WAR manually to a standalone Tomcat7 instance on each occasion :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i ended up with tomcat7:deploy for deploying (or redeploying update=true)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>pass</password>
            <path>/App</path>
            <update>true</update>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and undeploy with

```
curl -d "path=/App" "http://admin:pass@localhost:8080/manager/html/undeploy"
```

i needed this for jenkins

Answer (score 1):

the log indicates an issue with a not defined version in your pom.xml:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com:DocBookScratchProject:war:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 166, column 12
```

I would fix that first.

If undeploy fails it is often related to unclosed resources (like connection pools). usually you can try to undeploy, let it fail and have a look what files are still there. That often helps to identify the source of the problem.

there are some tomcat options related to deploy / undeploy:

- antiJARLocking
- antiResourceLocking

see: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

hopefully something helps here.

Comment: hm i think his problem is "FAIL - Tried to use command /undeploy via a GET request but POST is required", thats because of the old plugin written for tomcat 6. And the new one han't an undeploy command

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note here: You have to use the **tomcat7:deploy** goal **NOT** the tomcat:deploy goal, in order to make it work.