# Changes in source files of Maven project not reflected in tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

My maven project is in final stage. I have deployed my war file to running tomcat instance by using `mvn tomcat7:deploy` command and the war file is exploded in the webapps folder. I can access all the source files in the war file through url. But the problem is, when i change anything in my source files ( jsp and servlet ) the updated war file is not reflected in the running tomcat server. 
my pom.xml is as follows.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ceino.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MavenWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MavenWeb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <!--<warFile>/home/shebin/Maven Folder/MavenWeb/target/MavenWeb.war</warFile>-->
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/MavenWeb</path>
                <username>tomcat</username>
                <password>tomcat</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Am using maven 3.0.4 and tomcat 7.0.35. Pls help.

Comment: Just be sure, try invoking `mvn clean tomcat7:deploy`. I had a similar problem with JBoss.
Also, are you sure that the `tomcat7:deploy` goal rebuilds the project?

Comment: @Zoltán i have tried it. am not sure about tomcat7:deploy rebuilding projects. when i firstly call tomcat7:deploy the war file is moved to webapps directory of tomcat. But the updated war file is in my target folder of project. Its not automatically moved to webapps directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `mvn clean install` every time before running `mvn tomcat7:deploy`
If you still have the problem, try `mvn tomcat7:undeploy` before. The `undeploy` removes the old war file und the `deploy` try to push the new one

Comment: its also not working. as i have commented above ,  when i firstly call tomcat7:deploy the war file is moved to webapps directory of tomcat. But the updated war file is in my target folder of project. Its not automatically moved to webapps directory.

Comment: try mvn tomcat7:undeploy before. this will solv your problem

Comment: its showing  Could not find goal 'undeploy' in plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:. Is i need to update my pom.xml regarding this.?

Comment: remove the seven (7) and try it

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684952/tomcat-maven-plugin-using-tomcat-7-tomcatdeploy-works-tomcatundeploy-doesn

Comment: it works., i have added tomcat mojo plugin with server authentication. so, if i had changed anything in my project , then i need to run 'tomcat:undeploy' and 'tomcat:deploy' ...? it might costs me time.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and I solved it adding this to the pom.xml file:

Here I'm synchronising 2 folders:

src/main/webapp/resources -> target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/resources

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views -> target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/WEB-INF/views

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>          
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>              
            </configuration>            
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-views</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/WEB-INF/views</outputDirectory>
                <resources>          
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>              
            </configuration>            
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```